# Probability of certain Combination with each event having different probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Lets say there are 4 of balls, with each ball having a certain probability of being picked (A=0.1, B=0.2, C=0.3 and D=0.4).
3 balls are picked at random (same ball is not picked again):

1. What is the probability of the picked set containing ball A?
2. What is the probability of it containing ball A and B?

I understand through permutations we can calculate probability of each picked set containing ball A and add them up for answer 1.

- Is there a way to achieve this through combinations, if so how?
- Is there a generalized formula for this? (What is theory behind this called?)

## Edit 1

Thank you [@nicola](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/251928/nicola) for pointing out

3. Is it possible to calculate the new probability if ball A is picked, what is the probabilities of B, C and D ?.

Comment: The probabilities you listed are before the first draw. What happens after that? Suppose you draw $D$ as first. My understanding is that you cannot draw $D$ again. Which are the probabilities of picking $A$, $B$ or $C$ now?

Comment: @nicola thanks for pointing it out, I have updated the question

Comment: Shortcut - Hint for the 1st question: Picking $~3~$ balls to be selected is equivalent to picking the one ball that would not be selected.

Comment: Drawing a tree, with all options is a good exercize. You will spend some time, but if you do this seriously, it will help you to understand a lot of things, and after, you will be able to solve all similar questions.

Comment: @user2661923 I assume the new probability of B = P(B) * (P(A)/1-P(B))